# MongoDB subdocument reference ids

Tags: mongodb

Is there a "standard" or "preferred" method considering `_id`s when adding a subdocument that references a document in another collection? In `mongoose` and maybe other libraries, unless specified, `_id`s are automatically added to any subdocument, so I figure there must be a reason. Consider the two examples

Maintain a unique _id for subdocuments and prefix the referenced `event` document as `eventId`

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  event: {
    _id: ObjectId,
    eventId: ObjectId,
    name: "My Event"
  }
}
```

Or just set `_id` to the `event._id`

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  event: {
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: "My Event"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, seems like you want to access via `$lookup` a document that is in a different collection but also have a few fields from that document in the main doc. In that case, you don't need `_id` in the subdocument.

_id is what in RDBMS is called the Primary Key:

> The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array. [Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#field-names)

So your schema is fine IMHO with:

```json
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  event: {
    eventId: ObjectId,
    name: "My Event"
  }
}
```

`eventId` is what you'll use to access event details, it doesn't need to be called `_id` and can add confusion.